# Angular elements not known

Tags: angular

I am getting a problem where basic angular functions aren't being recognized. I have attached a screenshot showing the error. This problem has occurred in other questions on stack overflow however those solutions have not been effective. The specific example is of creating a dialog box. However, it I get a similar error when implementing the matDatepicker. Another thing of note is that i have a nearly identical dialog box component that does not raise this error. I know the error has to be with my import statements I am just not sure where and what to change. I believe I have correctly imported them in my app-module.ts file but still receiving the error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOghG.png)

here is the dialog box component .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Attendance} from 'src/app/models/attendance';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog-box_attendance',
  templateUrl: './dialog-box_attendance.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dialog-box_attendance.component.scss']
})
export class DialogBoxComponent implements OnInit {

  action:string;
  local_data:any;

  constructor( public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogBoxComponent>,
    //@Optional() is used to prevent error if no data is passed
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Attendance) {
    console.log(data);
    this.local_data = {...data};
    this.action = this.local_data.action; }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  doAction(){
    this.dialogRef.close({event:this.action,data:this.local_data});
  }

  closeDialog(){
    this.dialogRef.close({event:'Cancel'});
  }

}
```

here is the html file

```
<!-- dialog-box_attendance.component.html -->
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Row Action :: <strong>{{action}}</strong></h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="action != 'Delete'; else elseTemplate">
    <input placeholder="{{action}} Name" matInput [(ngModel)]="local_data.code_id">

    <input placeholder="{{action}} Name" matInput [(ngModel)]="local_data.hours_missed">

  </mat-form-field>
  <ng-template #elseTemplate>
    Sure to delete <b>{{local_data.typeName}}</b>?
  </ng-template>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="doAction()">{{action}}</button>
  <button mat-button (click)="closeDialog()" mat-flat-button color="warn">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

here is the app-module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { DefaultModule } from './layouts/default/default.module';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AlertComponent } from './components/alert/alert.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register/register.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JwtInterceptor } from './helpers/jwt.interceptor';
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './helpers/error.interceptor';
import { fakeBackendProvider } from './helpers/fake-backend';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AlertComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DefaultModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatNativeDateModule, 
    MatFormFieldModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule, 
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatFormFieldModule 
],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

    // provider used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

EDIT: [Project File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRnUx.png)

Comment: Try importing ```MatInputModule``` as well along with form field like, ```import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';``` .. Also give the same in ```imports``` array like, ```imports: [ .........  MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule ]```

Comment: No luck :(. Same error.

Comment: If possible create a stackblitz and reproduce your error there and share the link back.. Sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqzhyd

Comment: Also try importing separately like ```import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';``` and give the module name in imports array ..

Comment: Kolby, it looks like you are using `Modules` not like they should be used. Why would you need to add `@NgModule` and `@Component` at one class? You should provide us more details about your modules and how they look like, and what you export, import etc.

Comment: @KamLar I would like to preface by saying I am new to angular. I want to simply use the mat-dialog/ form field angular elements in my html file. I think I am supposed to import them in the app-module which will then allow me to use them. However, I am getting the error. Shown I directly importing them in the dialog component might solve the problem but it has not. So im not sure where I should import them. And whats even weirder is I have another dialog box module(for a different module) that runs with virtually the same html file with no problems.

Comment: Do you have any other `@NgModule` in your project? What is `DefaultModule`?  Can you show us what is it look like? Where have you declared 'DialogBoxComponent`?

Comment: @KamLar https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tw4jqa Here is a link to it uploaded on stackblitz, unfortunately there was some issue with the import paths so it does not run on stackblitz, only locally. But you can see the full project there.

Comment: @KamLar I solved my problem thank you for your help. As this is a group project, I was not fully aware of all the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Kolby, the "exports" is for export **Components** not module (it's used when we want use a component defined in this module in another component that is NOT in the module), e.g.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    CustomComponent
],
 exports: [CustomComponent]
})
export class AuxModule { }

@NgModule({
import:[AuxModule],
declarations: [
    AppComponent //<--AppComponent use CustomComponent
]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You need import the modules MatFormFieldModule and FormsModule (FormModule is for use [(ngModel)] in **each** Module that has a component that use this module -not only in the AppModule-

Comment: You can export `modules` inside `exports` and do not import them in `module` which imports this module. The same way you are creating `AppRouting.module`, you are importing `RouterModule`, configure it, and export, then in `AppComponent` you are no longer import `RouterModule` but `AppRouting`. The same you can do `SharedModule` and inside export everything that is/might be common.

Comment: sorry I did'nt know

Comment: @Eliseo  I have actually tried importing them directly in the dialog box component but get an error for having 2 incompatible decorators (which i assumed to be "@NgModule" and "@Component"). I have tried importing them in SharedModule but it does not solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that I have two "default modules" one named AppModule which I though was the default module and also DefaultModule which held the imports I needed. Declaring my components in the DefaultModuel fixed my issue.